# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, python-3.x

It would be greatly appreciated if I could have some assistance with an issue I'm experiencing with my code. The purpose of the code is to identify newly created directories, so that they can be manually added to a tape library for backup. The issue I get, and not always replicable, is it appears when a directory is deleted, the code falls over. This is the error I receive:

```
G:\Development\Python\Imaging In progress>Imaging_In_Progress.py
2015-03-02 08-41
{} Missing!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Development\Python\Imaging In progress\Imaging_In_Progress.py", line 21, in <module>
    seconds = os.path.getctime(dir)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\genericpath.py", line 65, in getctime
    return os.stat(filename).st_ctime
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'S:\\12345'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Development\Python\Imaging In progress\Imaging_In_Progress.py", line 27, in <module>
    print("{} Missing!").format(dir)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
```

I understand why the error occurs, although its not clear to me why it occurs on some directories and not others. I did attempt to add an exception in the hope that if FileNotFoundError occurred, it would be ignored and the script would continue. This appears to not be the case, perhaps due to the placement of the exception?

Please find my code below:

```
import time
import os

#Acquires current time
from datetime import datetime
current_time = str(datetime.now())
current_time = (time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M'))
print(current_time)

OUTPUT_FILE = ("{}.txt".format(current_time))

NEW_DIRS =[]

while 1:
#Acquires list of dirs and the creation date attribute associated to them 
    for dir in os.listdir("S:\\"):
        dir = os.path.join("S:\\", dir)
        if os.path.isdir(dir):

            try:
                seconds = os.path.getctime(dir)
                datecreated = (time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', time.localtime(seconds)))


            except (FileNotFoundError, IOError,AttributeError):
                print("{} Missing!").format(dir)


            close_time = "23-59"

            DATE_TIME = str(datetime.now())
            DATE_TIME = (time.strftime('%H-%M'))

            if DATE_TIME == close_time:
                    quit()

            elif dir not in NEW_DIRS and datecreated > current_time:
                with open(OUTPUT_FILE,"a") as c:
                    c.write("{}\n".format(dir))
                    NEW_DIRS.append(dir)
                    print ("{} added to array".format(dir))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code,

```
print("{} Missing!").format(dir)
```

`format` is called on the value returned by `print(...)`, which is `None`.  That's why you get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
```

The fix is to adjust the closing parenthesis:

```
print("{} Missing!".format(dir))
```

---

Keep in mind that whenever you see

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

it means that your exception handling code has raised an error of its own.  This can indicate that the code within the `except` clause is faulty.